# About exception handling in .NET

Tags: .net, exception

Suppose there is a .NET application that uses lots of system events and framework methods. I find it hard to manually read the documentation of each event and method to see if they throw exceptions. Is there a VS tool or a third-party application that runs through source code and indicates which events, methods, etc. are not exception handled?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way to automatically see which functions can potentially return exception in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915941/way-to-automatically-see-which-functions-can-potentially-return-exception-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most effective way is if the developer of the library uses the document comments to show what exception can be raised from a given method, but the assumes the developer bothered.

As StingyJack said the most likely way to get this information is to use reflection, this will need to be a recursive search and could tack some time, it probably will not show you any COM or Win32 Exceptions but should help you a lot.

Personally i would just wrap blocks of code in a try block and handle exceptions i know about and have a general catch all if it is that important.

Comment: Right - there's no point in catching specific exceptions if you can't do anything useful with them

Answer (score 4):

Redgate have a tool that does this, called [Exception Hunter](http://www.red-gate.com/products/Exception_Hunter/index.htm), though you will possibly drown in a sea of possible exceptions...

Answer (score 1):

Reflector has an Analyze command that may be useful for this purpose, but its not going to be as slick and quick as you would probably like